# Integration by Substitution, can't solve (Working Added )

Tags: integration

[image]

My Working:

> $$\displaystyle
> dx = du/2x$$
>   sub dx and U into equation

$$
x^2 \int x(U)^{3/2}   du/2x$$

Eliminate x 
$$
x^2/2 \int (U)^{3/2}   du$$

$$
x^2/2.  [2(U)^{5/2}/5]$$
then

$$
x^2(x^2+1)^{5/2} /5$$

this is what i get. hope you guys understand my working
i don't understand, should substitution method shall eliminate all the x? but now still left with x^2

Comment: $x^3=(x^2+1-1)\cdot x$.

Comment: @integrator i'm sorry sir, i did do the question but these 2 questions i really can't get and my lecturer didn't provide me any answer for it. and i'm been told the f'(x) should be higher power that f(x). Sorry to make you misunderstand sir

Comment: @Integrator thank you for your advise, i really appreciate it :) but i really means no harm or rude to ask peoples around for the answer without any effort, believe me, i'm might not a clever person but i did pay my effort just maybe my brain turns really slow. Please accept my sincerely apologize if i had offend any one of here.

Answer (score 1):

$u=x^2+1$, $du=2xdx$. Then
$$\int {{x^3}{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^{\frac{3}
{2}}}dx}  = \int {{x^2}{{\left( {{x^2} + 1} \right)}^{\frac{3}
{2}}}xdx}  = \frac{1}
{2}\int {\left( {u - 1} \right){u^{\frac{3}
{2}}}du}  = \frac{1}
{2}\int {\left( {{u^{\frac{5}
{2}}} - {u^{\frac{3}
{2}}}} \right)du} .$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer, may i know understand 1/2 ∫(u−1)u^3/2 du came out suddenly? i tried and all i get is U only :(